# ffmpeg configure always returns "not found" when using sysroot and cross-prefix options - how to use them correctly?

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg, cross-compiling

I try to build ffmpeg with a cross-compiler. When setting the configure flags I am getting the following errors:

```
WARNING: Compiler does not indicate floating-point ABI, guessing soft.
build_it.sh: 29: build_it.sh: --sysroot=/home/android/android-ndk-r9/platforms/
    android-9/arch-arm/: not found
build_it.sh: 32: build_it.sh.sh: --cross-prefix=/home/android/android-ndk-r9/
    toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-and
    roideabi-: not found
```

The error message "not found" sounds like the paths dont exist but they are all correct and existing. How can I resolve this error?

build_it.sh:

```
NDK=/home/android/android-ndk-r9
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86
CPU=arm
PREFIX=test
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"
platform="android-9"

./configure \
    --disable-asm \
    --enable-shared \
    --target-os=linux \
    --arch=arm \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --disable-static \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    --extra-cflags="-Os -fpic $ADDI_CFLAGS" \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS"
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --prefix=$PREFIX \

##configure fails here
...
```

Comment: Please publish your full `./configure` command line. You use a wrapper `build_it.sh` script; please disclose it, too.

Comment: Please find the wrapper script including ./configure in my edited post.

Comment: could there be trailing spaces in your `build_it.sh` file?

Comment: Or perhaps a missing \ after extra-ldflags?